# Select value from ComboBox and display it's details in textbox

Tags: database, vb.net, combobox, textbox, oledbconnection

I'm having some problem to display product details from two tables.

I'm using VS 2010, and MS Access Database.

My database table structure are as follow :

- Product (`#Product_ID`, `Category_ID`, `Product_Name`, `Product_Cost`, `Product_Price`)
- Category (`#Category_ID`, `Category_Name`)

What I want is to display `ProductCost`, `ProductPrice` and `CategoryName` into Textbox when I select `ProductName` from Combobox. I'm able to display `ProductCost` & `ProductPrice` but fail to display `CategoryName` because I not sure how to make this two table link together.

The code I use to fill Combobox with ProductName is :

```vb
Public Sub fillProductCombobox(ByVal sender As Object)
    Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        conn.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Product", conn)
        da.Fill(dt)
        sender.DataSource = dt
        sender.DisplayMember = "Product_Name"
        sender.ValueMember = "Product_ID"

        'best method?
        frmAddSalesProduct.txtProductCost.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Product_Cost")
        frmAddSalesProduct.txtPerPrice.DataBindings.Add("Text", dt, "Product_Price")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then I call the function this way on form load :

```
fillProductCombobox(ProductComboBox)
```

This is my how my form look like : [image: Form example]

Please guide me how to I display `CategoryName` as well.

Also is that the way I use to fill `Product_Cost` and `Product_Price` the best method?

P/S : For some reason I need to have everything done dynamically

Comment: Your structure says `ProductID` but you are binding to `Product_ID`.

Comment: Ah sorry it's Product_ID I got it wrong here :) Made an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the join query like

```
 SELECT Product_ID, p.Category_ID, Product_Name, Product_Cost, Product_Price, Category_Name
 FROM Product p
 INNER JOIN Category c ON p.Category_ID = c.Category_ID
```

So, you will get the category name using this query, just bind the text box as you are binding for others.

I hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Thanks Sir! I have never though of joining query before, has always been using INSERT, DELETE, & SELECT only. This really help me a lots! Thanks! :)